# How to generate a symmetric key with Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, cryptography, key, aes, bouncycastle

How can I generate a symmetric key with Bouncy Castle?
 Both [PrivateKeyFactory](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PrivateKeyFactory.html) and [PublicKeyFactory](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PublicKeyFactory.html) seem related to [AsymmetricKeyParameter](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/AsymmetricKeyParameter.html).

I don't want to know any JCA/JCE API - instead I'm only interested in Bouncy Castle specific API.

Can (should) I just generate a random bytes?

Comment: What symmetric key type do you want? Note: I edited your question to match what I think you were asking for (e.g. a BC-specific solution). If I've made an error, please correct it!

Comment: @DuncanJones Say, AES 128-bit key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AES does not have any weak keys, so a straightforward random generation should be fine.

```
// SecureRandom is expensive to initialize (takes several milliseconds) –
// consider keeping the instance around if you are generating many keys.
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(keyBytes);
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
```