# Encrypt string with Bouncy Castle AES/CBC/PKCS7

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, bouncycastle

I have been looking everywhere for some sample code on how to encrypt a simple string with the encryption in the title using the Bouncy Castle Framework.

This code will run on a Windows Universal project.
My previous attempts to encrypt using the build in API's failed to decrypt on the server.

I tried this: which gives me a string like:

> 4pQUfomwVVsl68oQqWoWYNRmRM+Cp+vNFXBNdkN6dZPQ34VZ35vsKn9Q7QGTDVOj+w5mqVYHnGuAOFOgdgl8kA==

```
s = String.Format("{0}_{1}", s, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHmmss"));
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider algorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
IBuffer keymaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("[Key]", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
CryptographicKey KEY = algorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);
IBuffer IV = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("[IV]", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
IBuffer data = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(s, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
IBuffer output = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(KEY, data, IV);
return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(output);
```

The server does encryption/decryption with

```
public static string Encrypt(string text, byte[] key, byte[] iv, int keysize = 128, int blocksize = 128, CipherMode cipher = CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.BlockSize = blocksize;
    aes.KeySize = keysize;
    aes.Mode = cipher;
    aes.Padding = padding;

    byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
    {
        byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
        encrypt.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string text, byte[] key, byte[] iv, int keysize = 128, int blocksize = 128, CipherMode cipher = CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.BlockSize = blocksize;
    aes.KeySize = keysize;
    aes.Mode = cipher;
    aes.Padding = padding;

    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
    using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
    {
        byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
        decrypt.Dispose();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest); //Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. 
    }
}
```

But it fails becasue:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

That's why I want to try Bouncy Castle, but I can't find any suitable example code.

### EDIT

I tried using Bouncy Castle with the code provided in the answer.
Now I'm getting the error:

> initialisation vector must be the same length as block size

```
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
byte[] IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

//Set up
AesEngine engine = new AesEngine();
CbcBlockCipher blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Pkcs7Padding());
Debug.WriteLine(IV.Length); //32
Debug.WriteLine(cipher.GetBlockSize()); //16
KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIv = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, IV);


cipher.Init(true, keyParamWithIv); //Error Message thrown
byte[] outputBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)]; //cip
int length = cipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
cipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, length); //Do the final block
string encryptedInput = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
```

The length on the server is 128. How can I force it to be equal and same length?

Comment: Edited the question with what I try

Comment: Can you replace the encryption by something secure?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Could you explain what you mean

Comment: Your key and IV initialization looks strange. Assuming each X represents one character you have an hex encoded AES128 key & IV but you don't decode the hex representation. Therefore key and IV are too long.

Comment: What result are you getting and what should you be getting?

Answer (score 20):

Here are snippets I use. It uses the default built-in System.Security.Cryptography. It doesn't need to be BC

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt a byte array using AES 128
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">128 bit key</param>
    /// <param name="secret">byte array that need to be encrypted</param>
    /// <returns>Encrypted array</returns>
    public static byte[] EncryptByteArray(byte[] key, byte[] secret)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (AesManaged cryptor = new AesManaged())
            {
                cryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                cryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                cryptor.KeySize = 128;
                cryptor.BlockSize = 128;

                //We use the random generated iv created by AesManaged
                byte[] iv = cryptor.IV;

                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptor.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(secret, 0, secret.Length);
                }
                byte[] encryptedContent = ms.ToArray();

                //Create new byte array that should contain both unencrypted iv and encrypted data
                byte[] result = new byte[iv.Length + encryptedContent.Length];

                //copy our 2 array into one
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, encryptedContent.Length);

                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypt a byte array using AES 128
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">key in bytes</param>
    /// <param name="secret">the encrypted bytes</param>
    /// <returns>decrypted bytes</returns>
    public static byte[] DecryptByteArray(byte[] key, byte[] secret)
    {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16]; //initial vector is 16 bytes
        byte[] encryptedContent = new byte[secret.Length - 16]; //the rest should be encryptedcontent

        //Copy data to byte array
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(secret, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(secret, iv.Length, encryptedContent, 0, encryptedContent.Length);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (AesManaged cryptor = new AesManaged())
            {
                cryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                cryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                cryptor.KeySize = 128;
                cryptor.BlockSize = 128;

                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptor.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(encryptedContent, 0, encryptedContent.Length);

                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you really need BC, here is a quick test I manage to write based on the test suit from https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/test/src/crypto/test/AESFastTest.cs
You can tailor it for your need

```
    private static void TestBC()
    {
        //Demo params
        string keyString = "jDxESdRrcYKmSZi7IOW4lw==";   

        string input = "abc";
        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);            
        byte[] iv = new byte[16]; //for the sake of demo

        //Set up
        AesEngine engine = new AesEngine();
        CbcBlockCipher blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine); //CBC
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher); //Default scheme is PKCS5/PKCS7
        KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(Convert.FromBase64String(keyString));
        ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv, 0, 16);

        // Encrypt
        cipher.Init(true, keyParamWithIV);
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)];
        int length = cipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
        cipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, length); //Do the final block
        string encryptedInput = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);

        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted string: {0}", encryptedInput);

        //Decrypt            
        cipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIV);
        byte[] comparisonBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(outputBytes.Length)];
        length = cipher.ProcessBytes(outputBytes, comparisonBytes, 0);
        cipher.DoFinal(comparisonBytes, length); //Do the final block

        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted string: {0}",Encoding.UTF8.GetString(comparisonBytes)); //Should be abc
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I like your effort, but AesManaged is not available for Windows Universal (correct me if I'm wrong).
Your code for Bouncy Castle however I don't see the padding PKCS7, IV nor an output string. I only need the encrypted string.

Comment: PaddedBufferedBlockCipher default uses PKCS5/PKCS7 (http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/paddings/PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.html)
For IV, you can wrap the keyParameter inside the ParametersWithIV
And output string can be obtained by converting the output bytes into Base64

Comment: Edited the BC part to PKCS7 + IV + output string. Haven't try anything with Windows Universal though.

Comment: The IV for AES 128 should be 128 bit = 16 bytes only. Just make sure you pass a 16 bytes array and it will be fine.
If you really need to enforce this will do:
ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv, 0, 16);

Comment: Did this work? Should I award the bounty? Or let it expire? What problems are you having @SeaSharp? Could you tell us what you are seeing and what you expect?

Answer (score -1):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54019372/3105004)

```
        byte[] k; //32 byte
        string para; // plaintext
        string msgRefNo; // 16byte

        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(para);
        byte[] IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgRefNo);
        byte[] key = k;


        AesEngine engine = new AesEngine();
        CbcBlockCipher blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher1 = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Pkcs7Padding());

        KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
        ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIv = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, IV);


        cipher1.Init(true, keyParamWithIv); //Error Message thrown
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[cipher1.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)]; //cip
        int length = cipher1.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
        cipher1.DoFinal(outputBytes, length); //Do the final block
        string encryptedInput = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
        return encryptedInput;
```