# How to encrypt plain text/string with BouncyCastle with public asc key in C#?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp

Does anyone have a simple example to encrypt a simple string using an asc public key file with C#?

I saw the documentation but it seems complex and always oriented to encrypt files.

Im still noob with pgp

Thank you all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encrypt string with Bouncy Castle AES/CBC/PKCS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701401/encrypt-string-with-bouncy-castle-aes-cbc-pkcs7)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan but no, the first one works without BC and the second one doesnt use .asc file. Thank you anyway

Comment: Have you looked at the 10 or so examples in the bouncycastle source under the `/crypto/test/src/openpgp/examples` directory?