# BouncyCastle AES Key Wrap - multiple of 8 bytes error

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to use BouncyCastle's AES Key Wrap in order to carry out deterministic encryption. But I am getting the following error:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.DataLengthException: 'wrap data must be a multiple of 8 bytes'
```

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var txt = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some text here.");
        var key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        var encyptedBytes = Wrap(key, txt);
    }

    public static byte[] Wrap(byte[] kek, byte[] plaint)
    {
        var en = new AesWrapEngine();
        en.Init(true, new KeyParameter(kek));
        return en.Wrap(plaint, 0, plaint.Length);
    }

    public static byte[] Unwrap(byte[] kek, byte[] ciphert)
    {
        var en = new AesWrapEngine();
        en.Init(false, new KeyParameter(kek));
        return en.Unwrap(ciphert, 0, ciphert.Length);
    }
```

How can I make it work for an input of any size?

Comment: Why should it work or an input of any size? Today's key sizes are multiples of 8 (an AES key is 16/24/32, Salsa20 32 and older DES is 8 or 24 when TDES). If you want to encrypt data of any size then use "regular" AES encryption.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I want a deterministic mode of operation.

Comment: The AES key wrap algorithm is intended for encrypting a key, see [RFC 3394](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3394#section-2). You seem to simply want to encrypt a plaintext, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29893607/9014097) (with and without BC).

Answer (score 1):

Use `AESWrapPadEngine` instead.   `AESWrapEngine` implements `RFC3394` which requires the input to be a multiple of the block size.  `AESWrapPadEngine` implements `RFC5649` which allows for the input to be any random length.